# Importing just DefaultUrlSerializer class into an Angular project without entire router module

Tags: javascript, angular, import, router, es6-modules

Following import statement pulls entire router module into the final webpack bundle.

```
import { DefaultUrlSerializer } from '@angular/router';
```

Is there a way to just import the `DefaultUrlSerializer` without other irrelevant module ?

I'm using Webpack module builder and Angular Cli for AOT/production builds.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you want to do. As DefaultUrlSerializer is part of the router module and has to be used with the router (expected it is used for the param in your routing file description). It is useless to import it alone, isn't it ?

Comment: I just want to consume the DefaultUrlSerializer as a library to parse a given URL and read URL segments or querystring....
In Angular 1.x it was straight forward $location.search().paramname

Comment: So far, DefaultUrlSerializer is export in the router module of angular.
so , you can not (at my knowledge) get it without gettings the full router module. the module importing/exporting system would be totally f*** up otherwise. I will wait for a mor eexperience guys to validate.
If you are in a hurry, you can still copy the class from angular and add it in your own project. sounds bad saying this !

Comment: I've added required info in the Original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do that unless you build the Angular yourself. The `npm` package doesn't ship modules separately, but as a one bundle in the UMD format:

```
  node_modules
    @angular
       router
         bundles
           router.umd.js
```

No matter how you import `DefaultUrlSerializer`, webpack will include the contents of the entire `router.umd.js` in the final build as it can't extract code from a file.

Comment: Based on your reply, I browsed through the node_modules folder and saw a single huge file for router... I was imagining that it was written in ES6 seeing all the export & import syntax while using Typescript. Those are just sugar coated declarations :(. Thanks for pointing me to the right directory.

Comment: @DavidChelliah, sure. `Those are just sugar coated declarations` - yes, it ships only declaration files

Comment: I didn't want to pull entire router module, so I removed all reference to @angular/routing and have replaced it with an alternative URL parsing NPM package - url-parse. Just linking a post showing alternative implementation https://davidsekar.com/angular/parse-url-in-angular2-